# Jooq queries don't see table data created via Hibernate models in unit tests

Tags: spring, hibernate, testing, jooq

I use Jooq for querying Postgres database.
Along with Jooq, we use Hibernate for creating entities.

I am trying to write an integration test.

In the method marked as `@BeforeEach`, I'm populating database with test data using Hibernate entities.

In the test case method, I call a service method `deliveryStatusSummaryV2Repository.getDeliveryStatusSummary`, which queries data from DB via Jooq queries.

The issue is that data added via Hibernate not visible (`final List<DeliveryStatusSummaryDTO> summary` is always empty) in the service method, which uses Jooq.

I believe the issue is related to a transaction isolation.

So the question is how to preserve wiping test data after every test case (transactional mechanism), and to make data visible by the service method that uses Jooq queries?

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class DeliverySummaryQueryBuilderTest {
    
    @BeforeEach
    @Commit
    public void before() throws SQLException {
        Cluster cluster = new Cluster();
        cluster.setId("cluster-1");
        cluster = clusterRepository.save(cluster);

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setId(MANAGER_ID);
        employee.setRole(EmployeeRole.MANAGER);
        employee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
        
        ...

    }

    @Test
    @Rollback(true)
    void test() throws SQLException {
        // summary is always empty
        final List<DeliveryStatusSummaryDTO> summary =
                deliveryStatusSummaryV2Repository.getDeliveryStatusSummary(
                        LocalDate.parse("2022-08-01"),
                        LocalDate.parse("2022-08-31"),
                        Set.of(MANAGER_ID),
                        Collections.emptySet(),
                        Collections.emptySet(),
                        Collections.emptySet(),
                        Collections.emptySet(),
                        Collections.emptySet(),
                        List.of(MANAGER, DAY, LOB, CATEGORY)

        );    
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that the data is not visible hints at your `@Commit` being ineffective for the `@BeforeEach` method (its Javadoc talks only about tests, not setups). That could explain why the data is not visible to jOOQ, though the *actual* problem seems to be that jOOQ's queries run in a separate transaction/connection? Why not re-use the same transaction/connection that you're using in your repositories? Note, you could also just use jOOQ to set up your `Cluster` and `Employee` test fixture using [updatable records](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/)

Comment: Hello @LukasEder. Thank you for the reply. I tried to remove `@commit` but data was invisible as well. For my Hibernate repositories, indeed there is the config which specifies entity manager factory, transaction manager ref, entity scan path, spring datasource etc. Regarding Jooq, I just use DSLContex. I don't setup connection/transaction explicitly for Jooq. Thank you for the advise about the updatable records.

Comment: Well, I'm not seeing your configuration, so I can't say whether you did it correctly. But my point about `@Commit` was that it may not apply to `@BeforeEach`, so removing it won't change anything, but keeping it there also won't do it. It's just a hypothesis. I've never worked with those annotations. I like things to be explicit, not magic... In any case, if the jOOQ query can't see your Hibernate data, you're not on the same connection, or your original changes haven't been committed. You have to fix either of these two.

Comment: @LukasEder Thank you again. Could you please point me to the Jooq docs where I can find how to make Jooq to use the same connection, which Hibernate uses?

Comment: There's no difference between doing this with jOOQ or with JDBC, so you'll find an answer when you look for how to extract a JDBC connection from Hibernate (e.g. with `session.doWork()`)

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the ideal answer here, given your specific question. Why don't you answer yourself and show what you did, *specifically* (e.g. using annotations, test setup, spring boot, etc.) That might be more useful to a future visitor of this question.

Comment: @LukasEder sure, I'll do.